# Annotate code in VS 2010 without changing that code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, documentation

I have just started a new job, and am trying to familiarise myself with a large C# solution, of 330 odd projects.  Ideally I would like to attach comments and questions to pieces of code without actually editing the code itself.

Is there a tool I can use to annotate C# source code without actually editing the code itself.  Ideally I would like a 'bubble' type comment mechanism, similar to how MS Word shows comments in a a document.

Comment: Have a look at code review tools, some of them could be used to annotate code. (but I've not really looked into that).

Comment: I have to do that also, I copy/past the code into notepad++ and add my comments into the new file.. You have benefit of Notepad++ syntax colorization

Comment: @bAN Do you mean customised colorization for comments etc?  Visual Studio does quite a good job of that anyway, and ReSharper puts icing on that cake.

Comment: I suggest a ream of paper and some colored markers...

Comment: @ProfK have you tried this one: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/80EA30B8-7766-4868-B9AA-D9F43A968BBB or this: http://stickynotes4code.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

you can add bookmarks to lines of files of a solution. In vs2010 there is a view that shows all bookmarks and you can give tem names and sort them in bookmarkfolders.

Comment: Thanks @k3b, but I'd like a little more that provided by just the bookmarks feature.  Also, if I use bookmarks for comments, I lose some genuine bookmarking functionality.

Answer (score 1):

On studio 2010, with your desired Project open, hit "Ctrl+W, T" (or View->Task List). This window can both be used to view in-code comments (which is not what you want) using the //TODO: comment prefix, or to view your own independente "User Tasks" (view the dropdown options), and it is saved per project. With this list indicating your descriptions and bookmarks id... you can have a very efective freeway to what you want without ever changing source. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It may well be overkill for your needs, but Atlassian's FishEye can be used to exactly what you're after - in the form of a source code review.

You could create more than one review, as your understanding of the code improves.

See https://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview. Note that it sits on top of a source control system (it supports Subversion, CVS, Perforce, Git, and Mercurial). Even if your code is not managed in one of these, it would be trivial to set one up for this purpose.

It also as the advantage of integrating your comments with those of other in your team ... and, of course, being usable for real reviews!